# Regarding Cassandra's (sloppy, still confusing) documentation on keys, partitions

Tags: cassandra

I have a high-write table I'm moving from Oracle to Cassandra. In Oracle the PK is a (int: clientId, id: UUID). There are about 10 billion rows. Right off the bat I run into this nonsensical warning:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html :
"If you create an index on a high-cardinality column, which has many distinct values, a query between the fields will incur many seeks for very few results. In the table with a billion songs, looking up songs by writer (a value that is typically unique for each song) instead of by their artist, is likely to be very inefficient. It would probably be more efficient to manually maintain the table as a form of an index instead of using the Cassandra built-in index."

Not only does this seem to defeat efficient find by PK it fails to define what it means to "query between the fields" and what the difference is between a built-in index, a secondary-index, and the primary_key+clustering subphrases in a create table command. A junk description. This is 2019. Shouldn't this be fixed by now?

AFAIK it's misleading anyway:

```
CREATE TABLE dev.record (
clientid int,
id uuid,
version int,
payload text,
PRIMARY KEY (clientid, id, version)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC, version DESC)

insert into record (id,version,clientid,payload) values
(d5ca94dd-1001-4c51-9854-554256a5b9f9,3,1001,'');
insert into record (id,version,clientid,payload) values
(d5ca94dd-1002-4c51-9854-554256a5b9e5,0,1002,'');
```

The token on clientid indeed shows they're in different partitions as expected.

Turning to the big point. If one was looking for a single row given the clientId, and UUID ---AND--- Cassandra allowed you to skip specifying the clientId so it wouldn't know which node(s) to search, then sure that find could be slow. But it doesn't:

```
select * from record where id=
  d5ca94dd-1002-4c51-9854-554256a5b9e5;
InvalidRequest: ... despite the performance unpredictability,
use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

And ditto with other variations that exclude clientid. So shouldn't we conclude Cassandra handles high cardinality tables searches that return "very few results" just fine?

Comment: Contrary to what the documentation seems to imply --- or doesn't because it's so crappily written --- this select *is very efficient*:

    select * from dev.record where clientId=1001 and id = 5bcd...ff and 
    version = 0

is just fine. If you try a select without the clientId you're warned you need a filtering clause and the result can be slow. So you can't even hit into a bad query by accident anyay

Answer (score 1):

Anything that requires reading the entire context of the database wont work which is the case with scanning on `id` since any of your `clientid` partition key's may contain one. Walking through potentially thousands of sstables per host and walking through each partition of each of those to check will not work. If having hard time with data model and not totally getting difference between partition keys and clustering keys I would recommend you walk through some introduction classes (ie datastax academy), youtube videos or book etc before designing your schema. This is not a relational database and designing around your data instead of your queries will get you into trouble. When moving from oracle you should *not* just copy your tables over and move the data or it will not work as well.

The clustering key is the order in which the data for a partition is ordered on disk which is what it is referring to as "build-in index". Each sstable has an index component that contains the partition key locations for that sstable. This also includes an index of the clustering keys for each partition every 64kb (by default at least) that can be searched on. The clustering keys that exist between each of these indexed points are unknown so they all have to be checked. A long time ago there was a bloom filter of clustering keys kept as well but it was such a rare use case where it helped vs the overhead that it was removed in 2.0.

Secondary indexes are difficult to scale well which is where the warning comes from about cardinality, I would strongly recommend just denormalizing data and not using index in any form as using large scatter gather queries across a distributed system is going to have availability and performance issues. If you really need it check out http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=13191 to try to get the data right (not worth it in my opinion).

Comment: I have been working with Oracle for over 25 years and have started working with Cassandra the past 3 years. I have learned a lot in regards to similarities and differences (and there are plenty). If you have questions, you can reach me off-line to discuss. The Cassandra indexes are no more than tables underneath it, which is where the confusing part comes from. It isn't a b-tree object which would be efficient, and thus harder to understand if you are thinking in those terms.

Comment: @Chris - well thanks for taking time to reply. But you didn't answer the question. You write "...scanning on id since any of your clientid partition key's may contain one." The PK is (clientid, id, version) e.g. partitioned by clientId to a node then (id, version) naming the row exactly. Moreover I didn't get any pushback on the fact that `select` doesn't allow you to hit into bad queries without explicitly adding filtering anyway. so my question end of post goes unanswered. The documentation sucks.

Comment: the *partition key* is `clientid` the *clustering key* is `(id, version)`. When not specified the first part of the primary key is implicitly the partition key - eg `((clientid), id, version)` The partition key is whats used to split up the data and is essentially randomly distributed. So you have to check every node, and every partition in the cluster to find any value of a single `id`. It cannot (and shouldn't) do this - even if you can force it with filtering.